# How to avoid black background when rotating an image 45 degree using PHP?

Tags: php, gd

Hi I have to flip a thumpnail image before merge it with another jpeg file. but when I rotate 45 degree using php. It shows a black background. how can I avoid that. any body can help me.

Comment: I don't think you can. The background has to be set to a color because JPEG images don't support transparent backgrounds. So if you rotate to some odd angle, it has to fill in those other pixels with some color. I just quit using PHP GD because it did so many random things and I could never get anything to work right. It's basically just a mess.

Comment: Hi sir sorry now me edited the question. if I rotate it 90, 180 etc. its k but I need 25 or 40 degree rotation. but at that time it shows this back ground

Comment: @learner: if you rotate 90, 180 etc the image will still be contained in the same "bounding box". If you rotate 45 degrees GD would not know what to put in the corner pixels as the original image did not have anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
$image = "130.jpg";
$degrees = 25;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    $ext = "";
    $extarr = "";
    $extarr = explode(".", $data[$i]['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($extarr);
    if($ext == "png"){
        $rotate = imagecreatefrompng("images/".$data[$i]['name']);
        $transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($rotate, 255, 255, 255, 270);
        $watermark1[$i] = imagerotate($rotate, ((360-$degrees)%360), $transColor);
    }
}

function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $opct){
    $w = imagesx($src_im);
    $h = imagesy($src_im);
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, (100 - $opct));
}


for($i=0; $i<count($watermark1); $i++){
    if($i == 0) imagecopymerge_alpha($image, $watermark1[$i], $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);
    else imagecopymerge_alpha($image, $watermark1[$i], ($i*$dest_x)*3, ($i*$dest_y)*15, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);
    imagedestroy($watermark1[$i]);
}
header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Also, do your watermark images have alpha channel or are they fully opaque?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you are generating a jpg, using PHP GD you set the color of the background as the third option of the function `imagerotate`. In this example I'm gonna assume that you are rotating a jpg image `$filename` by an arbitrary `$angle` degrees, and you want a white background, i.e. color code `16777215`:

```
$rotatedImage = imagerotate(imagecreatefromjpeg($filename), ((360-$angle)%360), 16777215);
```

black is color code `0`, which is default, and the rest of the color gamma is in between the two, so you just need to decide which background color you would like

EDIT:
for transparent backgrounds, if you are generating a png you would do:

```
$destimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($destimg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$rotatedImage = imagerotate($destimg, ((360-$angle)%360), $transColor);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: How can I make it as transparent. If I gave -1 it will also display white back ground.

Comment: @learner: Like I stated, you can't. JPEG images do not support transparent backgrounds.

Comment: can I change a jpeg file to gif format when it is uploaded. do you have any other suggestions for me.

Comment: @learner: animuson is correct in that you can't have transparent colors if the image you are generating is a jpeg, however if you would like to generate a png (heavier file size), then I would recommend checking out this page, where you can get ideas from the users' comments at the bottom of page http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Comment: @learner: yes, you may, 
see my comment and check out imagepng function at http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php
I would stay away from gif though, but png is the way to go

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: hello raine how can we make the background portion as transperant after rotating 25 degree. now i am using .png images but its not working with your codes. It still shows the black background. Please help me :(

Comment: @learner: could you post the updated code you are using? The code I posted works in my app, so I'd just like to take a look and see if i spot anything in yours that prevents it from setting a transparent background. Thx

Comment: Hi Raine this is my code

$image = "130.jpg";

//Hi raine this is my code I select all image details from the db. that is $data array. 

$degrees = 25;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
  $ext = "";
  $extarr = "";
  $extarr = explode(".", $data[$i]['name']);
  $ext = array_pop($extarr);
  if($ext == "png"){
   $rotate =   imagecreatefrompng("images/".$data[$i]['name']); // create watermark 
   $transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($rotate, 255, 255, 255, 270);
   $watermark1[$i] = imagerotate($rotate, ((360-$degrees)%360), $transColor);
  }   
}

Comment: ##after rotation I have to merge it with one main image. 

for($i=0; $i<count($watermark1); $i++){ 

 if($i == 0)imagecopymerge($image, $watermark1[$i], $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);
 
 else imagecopymerge($image, $watermark1[$i], ($i*$dest_x)*3, ($i*$dest_y)*15, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity); 
 
 imagedestroy($watermark1[$i]); 
}

//finally display the image
header("content-type: image/png");  
imagepng($image);  
imagedestroy($image);  

//it display the image but that black portion still exist

Comment: I see what you are doing. Even though it seems it should work, you can't just do an imagecopymerge, as it doesn't handle transparency of the png stamp correctly. I did a project a bit ago where I had to use a little workaround specifically for this. I will look it up tomorrow morning when I get to work and post the code here.

Comment: @learner: See my second answer above. The function imagecopymerge_alpha is the workaround to properly handle the alpha channel when superimposing PNGs, as imagecopymerge has always been bugged in that regard