# PHP GD Lib - Rotate image and add transparent background

Tags: php, gd, image-rotation

I am rotating a number of images (jpgs) by a few degrees. This results in the background of the rotated image to go black. I know I can set the background color of the rotated image like so:

```
$im = imagerotate($im , rand(-5,5), imagecolorallocate($im , $r, $g, $b));
```

But I am placing the rotated images on a transparent background. I've tried a few things like:

```
$im = imagerotate($im , rand(-5,5), imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127));
```

And:

```
imagealphablending($im, false);
$transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $transparency);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
```

But still no luck. I've also looked at this question: [How do i get a transparent background after rotaing a png image with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148774/how-do-i-get-a-transparent-background-after-rotaing-a-png-image-with-php/4148805) which doesn't work for me.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012051/how-to-avoid-black-background-when-rotating-an-image-45-degree-using-php

Comment: So it's pretty much impossible to fix this unless I convert my jpgs to pngs first which I can't do in this situation. Sigh. Thanks.